# How to add elements before other elements using javaparser?

Tags: javaparser

I try to add new `FieldDeclarations` to my `Main` Class in `CompilationUnit` before all other existing `FieldDeclarations`.

```
mainClassInCompilationUnitDeclaration.addPrivateField("Type", "fieldName");
```

Where `mainClassInCompilationUnitDeclaration` is a `ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration` representing the first declared Class in the `CompilationUnit`.

Unfortunately, all added Declarations get serialized on the end of the class.
This is logical as the elements are added at the end of the tree.

How can I change where they get added?
Is there any "insertBefore" in `Javaparser`?

Comment: In the meanwhile i found out that i can add new Members before existing ones via `mainClassInCompilationUnitDeclaration.getMembers().addFirst(field);` and `mainClassInCompilationUnitDeclaration.getMembers().addAfter(field, lastField);`. The Methods `addFirst` and `addAfter` are declared by `NodeList` which is not exposed by all Elements, so i cant use it for `LineComment`s for example as well.

Comment: You can also use the method add with a positional index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make a work around to handle this case for example you can make these steps:

1. Get the existing elements and save them in another reference and remove them from your 
   compilation unit .
2. Add the new elements you have made
3. Add the old elements again to your compilation unit

by doing that you now have the desired order.